# Как прокинуть статические файлы Django через Kong API getway

Tags: django, nginx

У меня есть приложение которое состоит из django, nginx, kong

Все компоненты развернуты через docker

Доступ к админке настроил через kong. Админка грузится корректно, но без статических файлов, то есть нет css, js, png. Потому что kong не знает как до них добраться. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ указать kong где лежать статические файлы?

Загрузка статических файлов идет через такие запросы

http://localhost:8005/static/js/registerSw.js

http://localhost:8005/static/js/site.js

и на все эти запросы получаю ответ 404